# What would happen if you used a dead person's hair in Polyjuice Potion?

Tags: harry-potter, potions, polyjuice-potion

Polyjuice Potion is changing based on someone's current physical state. It shows tattoos (or lack of) and such from DH when Ron changed to Harry.

> "I knew Ginny was lying about that tattoo,” said Ron, looking down at his bare chest.

What would happen if someone used hair of a dead person, taken from their body after death, and drank the potion? Would they die as well?

Comment: I reckon you'd explode.

Comment: or start puking rainbows? :P

Comment: To clarify: You mean hair taken from a dead person *after* they've died, rather than hair taken from them *before* they die? (Although, I wonder if there's a difference)

Comment: Is the assumption that it is based on the person's current physical state at the moment the potion is taken / made or when the item from said person was taken? Meaning - if they found a hair from Moaning Myrtle (which had fallen when she was alive) - would it be Myrtle as she was then when the hair fell or when the potion was made

Comment: yes. after they die

Comment: @CreationEdge In the latter case, Barty Crouch Jr. and his mother would be the case to consider.

Comment: The implications of this question means that polyjuice potion is actually fairly risky. Because if the premise of the question is true and you have the current health of the person you are impersonating, despite when you acquired the sample, then there's always the risk of a freak accident happening to that person between taking the sample and drinking the potion. This makes me believe it is more likely that you'll have the health of the person *at the time that the sample was taken* instead. This also requires less hand-waving to explain how the magic knows the target's current health.

Comment: All hair is dead to me, right @JackBNimble?

Comment: Unfortunately for Rowling there's a plot hole that must be explained away with magic (in a bad way); hair is dead already, so the potion wouldn't be able to tell a difference.

Comment: there may not be a canon answer, but this isn't opinion based.

Comment: @TylerH Who says the hair has to be alive? We're making potions, not growing clones - and the law of contagion only requires contact at some point in the past.

Comment: @user867 Did you notice the question is asking "what if the source is dead?"

Comment: @TylerH I did; I meant to reply to your point that 'the potion wouldn't be able to tell a difference' between a living hair donor and a dead hair donor by asking 'why would you think that?' Somehow, though, I got distracted during editing and added an off-topic and confusing question to the start of my comment. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**Unclear.**

> Then I packed up Moody’s clothes and Dark detectors, put them in the trunk with Moody, and set off for Hog- warts. I kept him alive, under the Imperius Curse. I wanted to be able to question him. To find out about his past, learn his habits, so that I could fool even Dumbledore. I also needed his hair to make the Polyjuice Potion.

He states that he kept Moody alive to question him so he is able to fool Dumbledore.

This line is unclear as to what it targets,

> I also needed his hair to make the Polyjuice Potion.

You can read this line as saying, "he needed Moodys hair", "so he put his body in the trunk", OR you can read this line as," I needed Moody alive so he kept growing hair that i could use for the Polyjuice Potion".

Neither option specify that the Polyjuice Potion **NEEDS** a living victim for the potion to work. That is pure speculation on our part via the text.

Its important to note that Barty Crouch Jr. needed a supply of hair for an entire school year, of potentially drinking the Polyjuice Potion every hour of every day. So would you risk just shaving his head and killing him, what would happen if you ran out of hair? Hence keeping him alive, to continue to **GROW** hair would be important.

Comment: Does it have to be hair from the head, or would any hair work? And how much hair is needed? Would a single hair work, or do you need more than one per potion?

Comment: @Xantec all valid questions, we've only ever seen hair from the head, per 1 hour in the books, so their is alot of speculation about how this potion works, what limits it has, ect.

Comment: @Xantec would you willingly drink a potion made from someone's hair, that comes from anywhere **other** than the head?

Comment: @MathiasFoster desperate times call for desperate measures

Comment: You don't even need hair for Polyjuice Potion to work, as per the instructions in Moste Potente Potions referred to by Hermione in book 2; you just need a part of the target's body. Thus if he'd killed Moody, he could've simply chopped him up into little pieces and used a bit of that each time. So that would suggest Moody needed to be kept alive for the potion to actually work.

Comment: @BolteAltamont  or that he didnt feel like chopping and bottling up some dude to then drink him

Comment: Wouldn't put it past Crouch. It also seems like a lot less effort than keeping Moody alive; you'd have to feed him and everything.

Comment: @BolteAltamont  but we already know he HAS to be alive to be questioned. First and foremost that is the reason hes still alive

Answer (score 8):

### It wouldn't work.

Simply because Barty Crouch Jr. kept Mad-Eye Moody alive in order to use his hair for the Polyjuice Potion. BCJ is not a nice man; he would presumably have killed Moody if he could rather than imprisoning him. He *needed* him alive for the Polyjuice.

> "I kept him alive, under the Imperius Curse. I wanted to be able to question him. To find out about his past, learn his habits, so that I could fool even Dumbledore. **I also needed his hair to make the Polyjuice Potion.** The other ingredients were easy. I stole boom-slang skin from the dungeons. When the Potions master found me in his office, I said I was under orders to search it."
>
> <sub>-- Barty Crouch Jr, *HP and the Goblet of Fire* (emphasis mine)</sub>

As for what exactly would happen if you tried to Polyjuice into a dead person, I don't think there's any canon info. Maybe you'd wind up dead yourself, in that person's body. Maybe the potion would simply have no effect: it works via a magical link with the biology of another living person.

Comment: I believe Dumbledore said that Barty Crouch Jr. kept Mad-Eye Moody alive because he needed him for questioning. But thats what had me ask question at first. What if you did it anyway, or someone forced u to drink it

Comment: @VanjaVasiljevic Please see the latest edit. Besides, needing him for questioning so as to be able to impersonate him convincingly wouldn't explain why he kept him alive *throughout the year*, after he'd already been impersonating him convincingly for months.

Comment: yeah there is no need to down vote just because you don't agree.  Still the quote doesn't explain what would happen if you drunk it. Maybe he knew and didn't want  it to happen to him.

Comment: Someone on [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/AskScienceFiction/comments/1bl3d4/harry_potter_polyjuice_potion_i_have_some/) has a quote from Advanced Potion-Making which says "**The donor of the aforementioned body piece must still maintain life for the effects of the potion to continue or function whatsoever.**" But I've no idea of the canonicity of this quote!

Comment: well AFAIK poly-juice potion isnt in advanced potion making, since that book is not in the restricted section, while most potent potion is, so id find that very suspect

Comment: @Himarm Polyjuice appears in Slughorn's class, and I thought students learn how to make it at *some* point during their time at Hogwarts. Are you *sure* a book on Polyjuice would have to be in the restricted section?

Comment: @randal'thor students never learn AFAWK, its in the restricted section according to book 2, which is why hermione had to get permission to check the book out, and its in slughorns class next to a banned love potion, and felix felicis, as examples of extremely complex potions

Comment: @Himarm    Not sure what "AFAWK" is, but the book from the restricted section was "Moste Potent Potions"

Comment: @EmilyCampbell as far as i know, i probably mistyped while drunk, thanks for mentioning the book.

Comment: Didn't BC Junior turn into his dead mum?

Comment: @user35971 Only while she was still alive.